# Vigenere segmentation fault

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
      {
      string p;
      int c;  
      if (argc >= 2)
      {
          p = get_string("plaintext: ");
      }
      if (argc != 2 || isalpha(argv[1][0]) == false)
      {
          printf("ERROR\n");
          return 1;
      }
      printf("ciphertext: ");
      string k = argv[1];
      int m = strlen(k);
      for(int i = 0,j = 0, n = strlen(p); i < n; i++)
      {
        c = p[i] + k[j % m];
        if(isupper(k[j % m]))
        {
            k[j % m] = k[j % m] - 'A';
        }
        if(islower(k[j % m]))
        {
            k[j % m] = k[j % m] - 'a';
        }
        if(isalpha(p[i]) == false)
        {
            printf("%c", p[i]);
        }
        if(islower(p[i]) && islower(c))
        {
            printf("%c", c);
            j++;
        }
        if(isupper(p[i]) && isupper(c))
        {
            printf("%c",c);
            j++;
        }
        if(isupper(p[i]) && !isupper(c))
        {
            c = ((c - 'A') % 26) + 'A';
            printf("%c", c);
            j++;
        }
        if(islower(p[i]) && !islower(c))
        {
            c = ((c - 'A') % 26) + 'A';
            printf("%c",c);
            j++;
        }
        else(printf("%c",c));
        j++;
        }   
        printf("\n");
      }
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what's wrong with my code. When I try to run it, I am able to get it to prompt me for a plaintext but I am hit with a segmentation fault if I try to go any further. I believe it has something to with the beginning of my for loop? I don't know if I declared variable `c` correctly. Other than that I really don't have a clue.

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
plaintext: hello
ciphertext: 
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdf18) at vigenere.c:24
24            for(int i = 0,j = 0, n = strlen(p); i < n; i++)
(gdb) 
(gdb) n
26                  if(isupper(k[j % m]))
(gdb) 
30                  if(islower(k[j % m]))
(gdb) 
32                      k[j % m] = k[j % m] - 'a';
(gdb) 
35                  c = p[i] + k[j % m];
(gdb) 
37                  if(isalpha(p[i]) == false)
(gdb) 
41                  if(islower(p[i]) && islower(c))
(gdb) 
43                      printf("%c", c);
(gdb) 
h44                     j++;
(gdb) 
46                  if(isupper(p[i]) && isupper(c))
(gdb) 
51                  if(isupper(p[i]) && isupper(c) == false)
(gdb) 
57                  if(islower(p[i]) && islower(c) == false)
(gdb) 
65                      (printf("%c",c));
(gdb) 
h66                     j++;
(gdb) 
68              }   
(gdb) 
24            for(int i = 0,j = 0, n = strlen(p); i < n; i++)
(gdb) 
26                  if(isupper(k[j % m]))
(gdb) 
30                  if(islower(k[j % m]))
(gdb) 
32                      k[j % m] = k[j % m] - 'a';
(gdb) 
35                  c = p[i] + k[j % m];
(gdb) 
37                  if(isalpha(p[i]) == false)
(gdb) 
41                  if(islower(p[i]) && islower(c))
(gdb) 
43                      printf("%c", c);
(gdb) 
g44                     j++;
(gdb) 
46                  if(isupper(p[i]) && isupper(c))
(gdb) 
51                  if(isupper(p[i]) && isupper(c) == false)
```

can anyone explain why h is printing twice even though the if statement is false? I was able to solve the problem but I am still struggling to figure out why c would output more than once for each iteration.

Comment: `isalpha(argv[1])` ==> `isalpha(argv[1][0])`

Comment: Whave you tried to debug the problem? Couldn't you run the algorithm with pen and paper, add some debug outputs to the program, and check step by step what's not working?

Comment: Having corrected the error I mentioned and using `scanf` because I don't have CS50, I ran the program with argument `qwerty` and entered the string `antidisestablishmentarianism` it output `TM[]ZJSawwUttzzbewwyyPcdZeeSbyydewwd` which is longer than the text entered. Ditto but the text entered was `one two` and the output is `HML` which is shorter than the text entered. Aside: don't use magic numbers like 65, use `'A'` etc.

Comment: shouldn't 65 work though? because that is 'A' on the decimal ASCII chart.

Comment: And what ASCII character is `111`? You have to look at the chart to know it is `'o'` or you can make the code readable. It might not be ASCII anyway.

Comment: Consistently prints the code of c (`printf("%x ", (unsigned int)(unsigned char)c);`) and the problems should become evident...

Comment: do any of you guys see any problems with the for loop?

Comment: You start the loop by using `k[j % m]` *before* you adjust the character in `k` in the following lines. You also need some more `else`s in there because `c` is sometimes output more than once in the loop. That is why the output is longer than the input (my bad earlier, it wasn't shorter).

Comment: Thank you so much! my code is finally working. Thank you for your time I really appreciate it.

Comment: ... by using more `else`s you won't have to keep repeating tests you already made, which will make the code more efficient and easier to follow. Whenever you output `c` the next code should be in an `else` block. That will close the holes in the flow logic.

Comment: My code is working but could you possibly explain why c is outputting more times for some of the loops. I don't understand why it is doing that. does it have something to do with the syntax?

Comment: Use a debugger. If you are unable or not willing to use a debugger, add `printf` for each interesting value at any interesting place and check if your program does what you expect. Using a debugger is the less expensive way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: anybody got any ideas as to why h is printing twice? The same thing happens to the rest of the letters

Comment: If you want to know what your code does use some meaningful names for variables. I want to help, but juggling through p,c,m,i,j,n hurts my brain

Comment: You have one more bug. You are checking only the first character of keyword argument. You should loop through all chars and check them with isalpha()

Answer (score 0):

You might get answer for your specific problem here, but if you want to solve it, and learn something (that's the point of cs50) take these steps:

- Try to solve it without any help first, if that doesn't work go through next steps,
- Watch [Zamyla's walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iE6jiKRfrEQ) and try to do it one step at a time,
- If you have a problem that seems too difficult, step away from the computer, grab a pen and a piece of paper and analyze what your program should do, and what it actually does,
- Learn to use the debugger (in cloud9 cs50 IDE it's on the right side of the screen),
- If your problem seems *really, really* hard turn off the computer and go to bed with a pen and a piece of paper, you'll be surprised how easier it is to solve problems while lying down :)

When you apply these steps, and solve your problem you'll gain some skills to solve similar problems and you'll feel smart :)

If you are a complete beginner at programming there are some really tough problems ahead (crack, speller ...), but if you apply these steps you can solve them all. I know, because I did, and I'm not an expert C programmer, super-smart or whatever, but my solution to 'speller' is now in top 10.
Be patient, and good luck :)